# Using Glob to get filenames with partial name inside folder to a list

Tags: python, glob

I have several files with the same format, but with different values.
with the help of StackOverflow users I got the code running, but now I am trying to optimize it, and I need some help to do it.

this is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd

# filenames
excel_names = ["file-JAN_2019.xlsx", "example-JAN_2019.xlsx", "stuff-JAN_2019.xlsx"]

# read them in
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]

# turn them into dataframes
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in 
excels]
#frames = [df.iloc[20:, :] for df in frames]
frames_2 = [df.iloc[21:, :] for df in frames[1:]]
#And combine them separately
combined = pd.concat([frames[0], *frames_2])

# concatenate them..
#combined = pd.concat(frames)
combined = combined[~combined[4].isin(['-'])]
combined.dropna(subset=[4], inplace=True)

# write it out
combined.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

the code that I am trying to use is as follows:

```
from glob import glob

excel_names = glob.glob('*JAN_2019-jan.xlsx')

files = []
for names in (excel_names):
   files.extend(names)

print(files)
```

at this moment i am getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "finaltwek.py", line 4, in 
    excel_names = glob.glob('*JAN_2019-jan.xlsx')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'glob'

but while I was tweaking with the code I also made the code run, but it found all the files in the folder, and I need only the ones that have the same designation in the end, including the extension

I am trying to make the code more dynamic by making it find all the files that end in the same way and are located in the same folder, but for some reason, I can't make it work, can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: `import glob` instead of `from glob import glob`

Comment: At the moment the error disappeared, but it returns an empty list, any idea why @Maurice Meyer?

Comment: check your working directory. Are the excel files in that location?

Comment: yes, I am sure of that, when i run the untweaked code, it runs fine, but I need to look at the files, specify them in the code. At any given time, I can have 100 files, and I need to find a way to do this without typing the name of all files---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glob.glob("*JAN_2019-jan.xlsx")` will search within the directory where the Python interpreter is located.
You can easily construct a file path by using `os.path.join(...)` and `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to point to your script's directory:

```
import os
import glob

excel_names = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '*JAN_2019-jan.xlsx'))
print execel_names
```

Prints for me:

```
['/tmp/ex-JAN_2019-jan.xlsx']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use glob.glob() then you should call

```
import glob
#then use 
file_names = glob.glob('*.xlxs')
```

In your code, you are importing the glob function from the glob file. In that case you cannot use glob.glob(). For your code:

```
from glob import glob
excel_names = glob('*JAN_2019-jan.xlsx')
```